# derivative of $\frac{u}{(u^{T}u)^{0.5}}$

Tags: derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

I am trying to compute the derivative of $\frac{u}{(u^{T}u)^{0.5}}$

I tried the following:

$\frac{\partial }{\partial u} (\frac{u}{(u^{T}u)^{0.5}})$

$=(\frac{\partial }{\partial u}u \cdot \sqrt{(u^{T}u)} - u \frac{\partial}{\partial u}\sqrt{(u^{T}u)} )/(u^{T}u) $

I get confused after that, can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Assuming $u$ is a vector, one needs to define the derivative with respect to a vector quantity.  See [THIS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we can start with the derivative chain rule, modified to fit in with partial derivatives. Just to refresh on that idea, I recommend you check out this article I found on the web: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-2-new/ab-3-1a/a/chain-rule-review

Now, using the derivative chain rule, you can get the answer to the first part. But wait, we're not done yet. Then you use the partial derivative chain rule again, so you can then get the final answer.

Hopefully this was helpful, and I've made the evaluation process clear. Now, If I haven't, just leave a comment and let me know your concerns and/or questions.

Comment: Thank you it is helpful :)

Comment: It was my pleasure. I like to help others often. Did you get the right answer?

Comment: I've edited my post. No big deal, it was just a simple grammar error.

Comment: One needs to define the derivative with respect to a vector quantity.  See [THIS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).

Comment: You have a point, @MarkViola.